# How to use this if condition under echo?

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button

This is normal radio button

```
<?php
$che='adi';
$che1='adi';
?>

<input type="radio" name="Owner" <?php if($che==$che1) {echo "checked";}?> value="A">A
```

I want this   php code in under echo for checked

```
<?php
$che='adi';
$che1='adi';

echo'<input type=radio name=ans  value=A>A';?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
echo'<input type=radio name=ans '.(($che == $che1)? "checked" : "").' value=A>A';
```

Reference :https://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples